# How do I bring back the little menu under the main window?

Tags: interface, shape-keys

[image]

So I'm working in Blender and I've just learned how to use shape keys through this awesome tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1KntZJCFUo

Except now that really helpful menu section(highlighted in red in the screenshot) is now gone and I don't know how to bring it back. I'm getting better with Blender but I would still count myself as a beginner/learner, so any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the upper and right corner of the red box in your 2nd image there is a small + click it and the small section will restore ;).

Comment: Holy Molly thank you so much, I was really stuck on that XD Goes to show even the smallest things are so easily overlooked, thanks again! :D